# Codeigniter unable to load requested file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I developed a site using the CodeIgniter framework. It's 100% working on my local server, but when I upload to www.000webhostapp.com it was unable to load some requested file.

[image: Here is my screenshot]

Here is my requested file method code:

```
public function user_list()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('role')==2 && $this->session->userdata('status')=="active"){
        $this->load->view('layouts/header');
        $this->load->view('hrm/user_list');
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
    }else{
        redirect('loginauth/index');
    }

}
```

Comment: care about file names case.can you show files in view folder

Comment: may it's `User_list.php` not  `user_list.php`.

Comment: yes, rewritte engine on.

Comment: The view that your loading views/hrm/user_list check spelling correct. On filename

Answer (score 1):

files are case sensitive in some servers. check your `user_list.php` file

Answer (score -1):

`mod_rewrite` must be enabled on the server. You should also make sure the server can read `.htaccess` on it's virutalhost configuration.

Comment: Can you translate this to English. Spanish questions and answers should be posted to https://es.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: Please use English.